# Apache rewrite to map # based URL into proper URLs

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Long version (you can skip to TL;DR if you want to):

I am working with a Wordpress site that was set up by someone else. The website has multiple pages where page has tabbed content which is accessible through #. For eg:

```
www.example.com/services/category1/#tab-service1
www.example.com/services/category1/#tab-service2
www.example.com/services/category2/#tab-service1
www.example.com/services/category2/#tab-service2
www.example.com/services/category2/#tab-service3
```

Now, when search engines index they are indexing only `www.example.com/services/category1/` and `www.example.com/services/category2/`. This creates a problem where we cannot have search engines point directly to the content within a given tab. What we want is for search engines to show links that takes users directly to (say) `www.example.com/services/category2/#tab-service3`.

Now, I don't think google can index such # based content on its own. So, I am thinking of using apache rewrites to try to resolve this issue. I have access to .htaccess file only (from a config perspective).

**TL;DR**

How to redirect `www.example.com/services/category1/service3/` to `www.example.com/services/category1/#tab-service3` using apache redirects (I have access to .htaccess file)?

This is what I am trying but it's not working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/services/category1/([a-z0-9])/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*       /services/category1#tab-%1           [R,NE,L]
```

Someone also adviced to look into pushState server config to fix this. I am not sure how to use pushState.

***UPDATE:***

I have updated the rewrites to the following but it still doesn't work. It keeps showing Wordpress' 404 page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/services/category1/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/services/category1/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /services/category1/#$1 [NE,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `%{REQUEST_URI}` regex is wrong. The pattern `^/services/
category1/([a-z0- 9 ])/?` matches `/services/category1/{any 1 char of a-z or 0-9}` format followed by an optional  slash. So this does not match your request `/services/category1/service3` but matches `/services/category1/a/` .

You should be using

```
^/services/category1/([a-z0-9]+)/?$
```

Comment: OK. I have done that. Still doens't work :(. See UPDATE in my original question.

Comment: You need to remove the leading slash from your rule's pattern. Change it to `RewriteRule ^services/category1/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /services/category1/#$1 [NE,R,L]`